# Can I disable O365 members button from my home page?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a site for which I would like to manage access requests. I can control who can give permissions, but I cannot control who adds who to the O365 group (see image). This ties to our group mailbox/calendar. Is there a way to disable this button so that users cannot add random people to the group? Right now, my site members group is messy with individuals that do not belong because my employees add them via O365 group.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn off members ability to invite other users to Office 365 group on the SharePoint site. Go to Site Permissions > Advanced Permissions and click on 'Access Request Settings' on the ribbon. Disable the checkbox 'Allow members to share the site and individual files and folders'

[image]

Comment: Sadly, this did not work. The membership button still persists and the option to add members is there. Why wouldn't that work?

Comment: Members will see the button but will not be able to add new users. This disables ability to add users to O365 group. Users may still be able to add users directly to SharePoint group which can be controlled using permissions.

Comment: Omg.... I am an admin. This is why I still see the button. Thanks for the solution. However now users cannot share files without permission. Why would they group these two things together? I think I'll still try for the code snippet above if I can find a way to get it to work.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to hide the members button in home page, we can use the [react script editor web part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) to achieve it. Add style below into react script editor web part in home page.

```
<style>
.ms-membersInfo-infoArea>button{
    display:none;
}
</style>
```

If you want to hide the members button in all pages, we can create a custom CSS style and inject the CSS on modern pages using SPFx extensions to achieve it.

The following solution with source code for your reference.

[SPFx Applications Customiser CSS Injection](https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-application-injectcss)

Comment: Thank you for the response LZ_MSFT, but react script editor web part is not available in SharePoint Online. There is a code snippet web part, but what language is this? CSS?

Comment: React script editor web part(not the OOTB script editor web part) works for modern site page.